React: Function call Working when called using UI component but not using Keyboard shortcut
I am building a React application where a MenuBar component has both UI buttons and keyboard shortcuts to trigger file-saving functions (Ctrl+S for Save, Ctrl+Shift+S for Save As).
The saveFile function in the App component uses the activeIndex state to determine which file to save. It works correctly when triggered via the UI button in the MenuBar. However, when using the Ctrl+S shortcut, the activeIndex is not updated, causing the wrong file to save or throwing an error.
How can I ensure that the activeIndex is synchronized correctly when using keyboard shortcuts?
MenuBar.jsx
import { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar';

function MenuBar({ saveFile }) {
    const handleKeyboardShortcut = useCallback((event) => {
        const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
        if (event.ctrlKey && key === 's') {
            event.preventDefault();
            saveFile(); // Trigger saveFile function
        }
    },);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardShortcut);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardShortcut);
    }, [handleKeyboardShortcut]);

    const menuItems = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            items: [
                { label: 'Save', command: () => saveFile() },
            ],
        },
    ];

    return <Menubar model={menuItems} />;
}

export default MenuBar;

App.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MenuBar from './MenuBar';

function App() {
    const [tabList, setTabList] = useState([]);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

    const saveFile = async () => {
        const activeTab = tabList[activeIndex];
        if (activeTab) {
            const content = activeTab.editorInstance.getValue();
            await window.electronAPI.saveFile(activeTab.path, content);
        } else {
            console.error('No active tab to save');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <MenuBar saveFile={saveFile} />
            {/* Other components */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;


From what I can see, saveFile is a new callback reference each time App renders, and passed to MenuBar via props. Each time MenuBar rerenders it creates a new handleKeyboardShortcut callback because useCallback is missing a dependency array, so it always has a current copy of saveFile. The useEffect hook using handleKeyboardShortcut as a dependency will also update each render cycle and attach the current handleKeyboardShortcut to the "keydown" event listener. As far as I can tell your code should be working as expected, albeit a little unoptimized.
